# Trouble Making A simple AI

Tags: vb.net

I am currently trying to make a tic-tac-toe game where the pc randomly choses a number from an array  and, according to the number, it chooses a button and changes it's text property. How would I make it not choose a button that already has a text property? Here is my code:

```
   Dim AIChoice As Integer
   AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length - 1)

   If AI.GetValue(AIChoice) = 1 And Button1.Text = "" Then
       Button1.Text = "O"
       AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
   ElseIf AI.GetValue(AIChoice) = 2 And Button2.Text = "" Then
       Button2.Text = "O"
       AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
   ElseIf AI.GetValue(AIChoice) = 3 And Button3.Text = "" Then
       Button3.Text = "O"
       AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
   ElseIf AI.GetValue(AIChoice) = 4 And Button4.Text = "" Then
       Button4.Text = "O"
       AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
   ElseIf AI.GetValue(AIChoice) = 5 And Button5.Text = "" Then
       Button5.Text = "O"
       AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
   ElseIf AI.GetValue(AIChoice) = 6 And Button6.Text = "" Then
       Button6.Text = "O"
       AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
   ElseIf AI.GetValue(AIChoice) = 7 And Button7.Text = "" Then
       Button7.Text = "O"
       AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
   ElseIf AI.GetValue(AIChoice) = 8 And Button8.Text = "" Then
       Button8.Text = "O"
       AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
   ElseIf AI.GetValue(AIChoice) = 9 And Button9.Text = "" Then
       Button9.Text = "O"
       AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
```

I Also Have an array earlier with the numbers 1-9 on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should function identically to the code you posted, except that it will keep picking a random number until it finds a button with an empty string as its `Text`. Note that it would be better to create the buttons as an array rather create an additional array to refer to them, but this is the simplest fix and I don't think you'll run into any problems that the other way would avoid.

```
Dim AllButtons() As Button = {Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4, Button5, Button6, Button7, Button8, Button9}
Dim AIChoice As Integer
Do
    AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length - 1)
Loop Until AllButtons(AI.GetValue(AIChoice) - 1).Text = ""
AllButtons(AI.GetValue(AIChoice) - 1).Text = "O"
AIChoice = AIChoic.Next(0, AI.Length)
```

Comment: I assumed that `AIChoice` and `AIChoic` were two separate variables. If that was a typo in your post, it will need to be corrected here too.

Comment: Thanks but i found a way to make it work with if statements and a lot of them. Also i made it to where it can see if the player is about to get a tic tac toe